# How do I prevent yii change the class of a component after render a CactiveForm

Tags: php, forms, class, yii, render

I had problems because when the controller validates the form this will change the class of components and these are not displayed properly.
example:

**Before submit:**

```
<input type="text" name="Fidpersoon[datumaanvraag]" 
  style="height:20px; width:90%" 
  id="Fidpersoon_datumaanvraag0" class="hasDatepicker">
```

**After submit:**

```
<input type="text" class="error" value="" name="Fidpersoon[datumaanvraag]"
  style="height:20px;width:90%"
  id="Fidpersoon_datumaanvraag0">
```

as you can see by changing the class, the datepicker is not shown, just a normal input is shown.

how fix this?

Comment: Please provide more code ie controller code. Is this using Ajax?

Comment: i don't use ajax for submit and the controller is standar controller generated by gii.

Comment: the only way i found to deal with this error is creating again the jquery components:$(function() {
 $('#Fidpersoon_datumaanvraag<?php echo $index?>').datepicker();
});